# Sequelize, problem with requesting products with ratings and tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The problem with the request in which products with tags and their rating are selected. I can’t solve the problem for 2 months, I really need help.

Ralations:

```
const models = require("./models");

const initRelations = () => {
  models.Product.belongsToMany(models.Tag, { through: "ProductTag" });

  models.Tag.belongsToMany(models.Product, { through: "ProductTag" });

  models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, { through: "UserRoles" });

  models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: "UserRoles" });

  models.User.hasMany(models.Rating);

  models.Product.hasMany(models.Rating);

  models.Rating.belongsTo(models.Product);

  models.Rating.belongsTo(models.User);
};
module.exports = { initRelations };
```

Request:

```
const products = await models.Product.findAll({
        subQuery: false,

        offset,

        limit: Number(amount),

        where: whereOptions,

        order: orderOptions,

        attributes: [
          "id",
          "price",
          "title",
          "amount",
          "description",
          "picture",
          "createdAt",
          "updatedAt",

          [
            sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratings.ratingValue")),
            "averageRating"
          ],

          [
            sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratings.ratingValue")),
            "amountOfRatings"
          ]
        ],

        include: [
          {
            model: models.Rating,
            required: false,
            attributes: ["ratingValue", "productId"]
          },
          {
            model: models.Tag,
            attributes: []
          }
        ],

        group: ["products.id"]
      });
```

Error:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Expression #11 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'omVapeShop.ratings.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
mainserver       |     at Query.formatError (/app/mainserver/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:244:16)
mainserver       |     at Query.handler [as onResult] (/app/mainserver/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:51:23)
mainserver       |     at Query.execute (/app/mainserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:14)
mainserver       |     at Connection.handlePacket (/app/mainserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
mainserver       |     at PacketParser.onPacket (/app/mainserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
mainserver       |     at PacketParser.executeStart (/app/mainserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
mainserver       |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/mainserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
mainserver       |     at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
mainserver       |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
mainserver       |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
mainserver       |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
mainserver       |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
mainserver       |   name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
```

Request(sql):

```
Executing (default): SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`price`, `product`.`title`, `product`.`amount`, `product`.`description`, `product`.`picture`, `product`.`createdAt`, `product`.`updatedAt`, avg(`ratings`.`ratingValue`) AS `averageRating`, count(`ratings`.`ratingValue`) AS `amountOfRatings`, `ratings`.`id` AS `ratings.id`, `ratings`.`ratingValue` AS `ratings.ratingValue`, `ratings`.`productId` AS `ratings.productId`, `tags->ProductTag`.`createdAt` AS `tags.ProductTag.createdAt`, `tags->ProductTag`.`updatedAt` AS `tags.ProductTag.updatedAt`, `tags->ProductTag`.`productId` AS `tags.ProductTag.productId`, `tags->ProductTag`.`tagId` AS `tags.ProductTag.tagId` FROM `products` AS `product` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` AS `ratings` ON `product`.`id` = `ratings`.`productId` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `ProductTag` AS `tags->ProductTag` INNER JOIN `tags` AS `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `tags->ProductTag`.`tagId`) ON `product`.`id` = `tags->ProductTag`.`productId` GROUP BY `product`.`id` ORDER BY `product`.`amount` DESC LIMIT 0, 3;
```

I need to get products with tags, as well as a field where there will be an average rating and the number of ratings

If you need any more data, I’ll definitely throw it off

Answer (score 0):

If you use aggregate function then you should indicate all columns that is not participating in aggregate functions in the **group** param. In your case these ones will be:

```
"id",
"price",
"title",
"amount",
"description",
"picture",
"createdAt",
"updatedAt",
```

and all columns in inludes:

```
attributes: ["ratingValue", "productId"]
```

Comment: I dont understand,can you fix my Request,please

Comment: If I understand you :

 group: [
          "id",
          "price",
          "title",
          "amount",
          "description",
          "picture",
          "createdAt",
          "updatedAt",
          "ratingValue",
          "productId"
        ]

Comment: original: Error: Column 'productId' in group statement is ambiguous 
if I use  group: [ "id", "price", "title", "amount", "description", "picture", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "ratingValue", "productId" ]

Comment: thank you so much,realy,so much. Everything is work )

Answer (score 0):

Work:

```
const products = await models.Product.findAll({
        subQuery: false,

        offset,

        limit: Number(amount),

        where: whereOptions,

        order: orderOptions,

        attributes: [
          "id",
          "price",
          "title",
          "amount",
          "description",
          "picture",
          "createdAt",
          "updatedAt",

          [
            sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratings.ratingValue")),
            "averageRating"
          ],

          [
            sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratings.ratingValue")),
            "amountOfRatings"
          ]
        ],

        include: [
          {
            model: models.Rating,
            required: false,
            attributes: []
          },
          {
            model: models.Tag,
            attributes: ["text", "id"],
            through: {
              attributes: []
            }
          }
        ],

        group: [
          "id",
          "price",
          "title",
          "amount",
          "description",
          "picture",
          "createdAt",
          "updatedAt",
          "text",
          "product.id",
          "tags.id"
        ]
      });
```